# Cannot connect to jhipster spring registry on docker via IDE

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, jhipster, spring-cloud-config

I'm running JHipster registry in a docker container.
All applications **running on docker** can connect and register in registry endpoint (port 8761).

But when I try to connect an application running on my IDEA, I receive a error when trying to connect to the registry endpoint:

```
2016-07-21 10:35:24.912  INFO 1455 --- [  restartedMain] a.b.p.App2App             : Started App2App in 14.944 seconds (JVM running for 15.912)
2016-07-21 10:35:24.913  INFO 1455 --- [  restartedMain] a.b.p.App2App             : 
----------------------------------------------------------
    Application 'app2' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://127.0.0.1:8081
    External:   http://192.168.1.104:8081
----------------------------------------------------------
2016-07-21 10:35:24.913  INFO 1455 --- [  restartedMain] a.b.p.App2App             : 
----------------------------------------------------------
    Config Server:  Connected to the JHipster Registry running in Docker
----------------------------------------------------------
2016-07-21 10:35:24.915 DEBUG 1455 --- [nfoReplicator-0] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@33e72d406 pairs: {GET /config/application/prod/master HTTP/1.1: null}{Accept: application/json, application/*+json}{Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=}{User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_65}{Host: localhost:8761}{Connection: keep-alive}
2016-07-21 10:35:25.057 DEBUG 1455 --- [nfoReplicator-0] s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection  : sun.net.www.MessageHeader@d6320d811 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK}{Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1}{X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff}{X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block}{Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate}{Pragma: no-cache}{Expires: 0}{X-Application-Context: jhipster-registry:dev,native:8761}{Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8}{Transfer-Encoding: chunked}{Date: Thu, 21 Jul 2016 13:35:24 GMT}
2016-07-21 10:35:25.058  INFO 1455 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_APP2/app2:cddc722884843f95abdcf09d4996623d: registering service...
2016-07-21 10:35:25.059 ERROR 1455 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.UnknownHostException: registry
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123)
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.register(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:810)
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:103)
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:87)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: registry
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173)
    ... 30 common frames omitted

2016-07-21 10:35:25.059  WARN 1455 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failure
2016-07-21 10:35:25.060  WARN 1455 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_APP2/app2:cddc722884843f95abdcf09d4996623d - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:810)
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:103)
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:87)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2016-07-21 10:35:25.060  WARN 1455 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : There was a problem with the instance info replicator

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:810)
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:103)
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:87)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The application connects to Register (see it in logs), but after that I receive the error:

```
UnknownHostException: registry
```

Did anyone know how can I connect to a registry running in docker?

My spring application.yml is:

```
eureka:
    instance:
        prefer-ip-address: true
    client:
        enabled: true
        healthcheck:
            enabled: true
        registerWithEureka: true
        fetchRegistry: true
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://admin:admin@localhost:8761/eureka/
```

The default zone in jhipster-registry is http://user:pass@register:8761/eureka.

If I change to localhost, like this:

```
eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://admin:admin@localhost:8761/eureka/
```

It works, but in this case the services running in docker can't access the registry (reverse problem).

Thanks!

Comment: In IDEA, I always have to configure the working directory to be MODULE_DIR in the run target, otherwise app fails finding its config file. Also, the important file is bootstrap.yml not application.yml, because the registry is also a spring cloud config server.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou the classpath of module? Here is the config files and the config in IDEA: https://gist.github.com/cavarzan/6b27476baaf8f4dfefc347c9d51931fb

Comment: Working directory and it looks good from what I see. I'm sorry I can't help you more, I don't use Docker to run JHipster microservices, I prefer to run them directly in java, it's easier for debugging.

Comment: I'm running the main class directly. I also created as a gradle project.

Comment: Yes that's what I do for main class also, so why don't you do the same for the regsitry? It uses less resources on your PC when developing.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou thanks! I'm try to avoid to run a lot of services at the same time, docker will made it easier. But thanks much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.  In 3.5.0, I was able to successfully start the docker based registry, and then start up non docker versions of a microservice and a gateway.  With 3.5.1, I was no longer able to do that, getting the same error you are getting.  I think it's related to https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/3848.  In any case, I just added an entry in my /etc/hosts file, pointing "registry" to 127.0.0.1, and it worked.

Comment: This one worked for me also. I added "jhipster-registry" in my localhost pointing 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

The localhost on docker which running microservice is not the same localhost on docker which running registry. I changed the localhost to the host's Intranet Address, It's work for me.

```
eureka:
    instance:
        prefer-ip-address: true
    client:
        service-url:
            defaultZone: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@10.31.224.228:8761/eureka/
```